# Would we benefit from a tag that indicates a text-block scoring criterion?

Tags: discussion, tags

A number of times now I have posted challenges where a rectangular block of text is the submission requirement. These are usually [source-layout](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-layout) challenges.

Examples: (other users surely have some too)
[Sierpinskified Code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47063/26997)
[Code that runs the Game of Life on itself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/35974/26997)
[Write a Rectangular Program that Outputs the Number of Times it was Rotated](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/33150/26997)

The area of the submitted text block (width times height, excluding the newlines) is the score for these challenges. The smallest area winning.

Tagging them [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is not entirely accurate since the byte/character count of the text blocks is not the score unless you remove the newlines (many times I have noticed answers with incorrect score calculations). Tagging them [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) may be technically more accurate, but the challenge is still about minizing the amount of code, which is why I've tagged some [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Could we benefit ftom a new tag that indicates this "text-block scoring"?

(I personally have no strong feelings either way.)

Comment: We might as well just have a tag [tag:ch-allenge] :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## No

This would be unnecessary. We should tag them as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) since that's what they essentially are.

Comment: +1 No need for [code-golf-minus-newlines]. I think [code-golf][source-layout] conveys the message pretty well.

Comment: Agreed. We don't use a separate tag for "code golf but don't count whitespace" either.

Answer (score -4):

## Yes

We would benefit. (We'd still need to name the tag of course.)

Answer (score -8):

## No

This would be unnecessary. But we should tag them as [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) and be sure to explain that the smallest area wins.